# Is there any way to upload folder using laravel and vue js?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Right now I have a project similar to this https://bedrive.vebto.com/drive .

I want to add feature upload the whole folder with files inside the folder like we upload folder in google drive.

I'm using this code in input but I can't get anything in file when I upload folder.

```
<input     
            accept="*"
            v-show="false"
            @change="emmitFiles"
            id="file"
            type="file"
            name="files[]"
            multiple
            webkitdirectory=""
            directory=""
    />
```

I'm using vuejs and laravel so how can I do these things?

Please help me to solve this and also sorry for my bad English.